# Golang (GO) Channels Problem While Trying To Implement (Replicate) DB/Cache Querying Scenario

Tags: go, goroutine

So i'm new to channels, waitgroups, mutex etc, and tried to create an application that queries a slice of a struct for data and if it finds the data it loads it into a map.
I'm basically trying to replicate a cache/db scenario (but having both in memory currently for ease of understanding).

Now, while querying the data, it gets queried both from the db and cache and i've put up an RWMutex for this; but while reading the data stored into either the cache or db using another go routines (via channels). It reads from both the (db go-routine) and the (cache go-routine). So what I did was everytime i get a read from cache go-routine i drain the db go-routing of one element.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Book struct {
    id   int
    name string
}

var cache = map[int]Book{}
var books []Book
var rnd = rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))

func main() {
    cacheCh := make(chan Book)
    dbCh := make(chan Book)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    m := &sync.RWMutex{}
    loadDb()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        id := rnd.Intn(10)
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(id int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, m *sync.RWMutex, ch chan<- Book) {
            if find, book := queryCache(id, m); find {
                fmt.Println("Found Book In Cache: ", book)
                ch <- book
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(id, wg, m, cacheCh)
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(id int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, m *sync.RWMutex, ch chan<- Book) {
            if find, book := queryDb(id, m); find {
                ch <- book
            }
            wg.Done()
        }(id, wg, m, dbCh)
        go func(dbCh, cacheCh <-chan Book) {
            var book Book
            select {
            case book = <-cacheCh:
                msg := <-dbCh
                fmt.Println("Drain DbCh From: ", msg, "\nBook From Cache: ", book.name)
            case book = <-dbCh:
                fmt.Println("Book From Database: ", book.name)
            }
        }(dbCh, cacheCh)
    }

    wg.Wait()
}

func queryCache(id int, m *sync.RWMutex) (bool, Book) {
    m.RLock()
    b, ok := cache[id]
    m.RUnlock()
    return ok, b
}
func queryDb(id int, m *sync.RWMutex) (bool, Book) {
    for _, val := range books {
        if val.id == id {
            m.Lock()
            cache[id] = val
            m.Unlock()
            return true, val
        }
    }
    var bnf Book
    return false, bnf

}

func loadDb() {
    var book Book
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        book.id = i
        book.name = "a" + strconv.Itoa(i)
        books = append(books, book)
    }

}
```

Also, I understand that in this code it will always query the db even if it finds a hit at the cache which is not ideal. But, this is just a test scenario where all that I have put as a priority is that the user receives the details in the fastest mode possible (ie if it is not present in the cache it shouldn't wait for a response from the cache before querying the db).

Please help if possible, i'm pretty new to this so it might be something trivial.

Sorry and Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issues I can see mainly relate to assumptions about the order in which things will execute:

- You are assuming that the db/cache retrieval go routines will return in order; there is no guarantee of this (in theory the last book requested could be added to the channel first and the entries on the cache chanel are likely to be ordered differently to the db channel).
- The above point negates your extra `msg := <-dbCh` (because the database could return a result before the cache and, in that case, the channel is not drained). This leads to a deadlock.
- Your code exits when the waitgroup completes and this can, and probably will, happen before the go routine that retrieves the results completes (the go routine with the `select` does not utilise the wait group) - this is not actually a problem because your code hits a deadlock before that point.

The code below ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Zi0pd8slz92)) is my attempt to address these issues while leaving your code mostly as-is (I did create a `getBook` function because I think this makes it easier to understand). I'm not going to guarantee that my code is error free but hopefully it helps.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "strconv"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Book struct {
    id   int
    name string
}

var cache = map[int]Book{}
var books []Book
var rnd = rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())) // Note: Not random on playground as time is simulated

func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    m := &sync.RWMutex{}
    loadDb()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        id := rnd.Intn(10)
        wg.Add(1) // Could also add 10 before entering the loop
        go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, m *sync.RWMutex, id int) {
            getBook(m, id)
            wg.Done() // The book has been retrieved; loop can exit when all books retrieved
        }(wg, m, id)
    }
    wg.Wait() // Wait until all books have been retrieved
}

// getBook will retrieve a book (from the cache or the db)
func getBook(m *sync.RWMutex, id int) {
    fmt.Printf("Requesting book: %d\n", id)
    cacheCh := make(chan Book)
    dbCh := make(chan Book)
    go func(id int, m *sync.RWMutex, ch chan<- Book) {
        if find, book := queryCache(id, m); find {
            //fmt.Println("Found Book In Cache: ", book)
            ch <- book
        }
        close(ch)
    }(id, m, cacheCh)
    go func(id int, m *sync.RWMutex, ch chan<- Book) {
        if find, book := queryDb(id, m); find {
            ch <- book
        }
        close(ch)
    }(id, m, dbCh)

    // Wait for a result from one of the above - Note that we make no assumptions
    // about the order of the results but do assume that dbCh will ALWAYS return a book
    // We want to return from this function as soon as a result is received (because in reality
    // we would return the result)
    for {
        select {
        case book, ok := <-cacheCh:
            if !ok { // Book is not in the cache so we need to wait for the database query
                cacheCh = nil // Prevents select from considering this
                continue
            }
            fmt.Println("Book From Cache: ", book.name)
            drainBookChan(dbCh) // The database will always return something (in reality you would cancel a context here to stop the database query)
            return
        case book := <-dbCh:
            dbCh = nil // Nothing else will come through this channel
            fmt.Println("Book From Database: ", book.name)
            if cacheCh != nil {
                drainBookChan(cacheCh)
            }
            return
        }
    }
}

// drainBookChan starts a go routine to drain the channel passed in
func drainBookChan(bChan chan Book) {
    go func() {
        for _ = range bChan {
        }
    }()
}

func queryCache(id int, m *sync.RWMutex) (bool, Book) {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(rnd.Intn(100)) * time.Millisecond) // Introduce some randomness (otherwise everything comes from DB)
    m.RLock()
    b, ok := cache[id]
    m.RUnlock()
    return ok, b
}
func queryDb(id int, m *sync.RWMutex) (bool, Book) {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(rnd.Intn(100)) * time.Millisecond) // Introduce some randomness (otherwise everything comes from DB)
    for _, val := range books {
        if val.id == id {
            m.Lock()
            cache[id] = val
            m.Unlock()
            return true, val
        }
    }
    var bnf Book
    return false, bnf

}

func loadDb() {
    var book Book
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        book.id = i
        book.name = "a" + strconv.Itoa(i)
        books = append(books, book)
    }

}
```